# Is it possible to disable Alt click in Autohotkey v2.0.2?

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey v1.3. I disabled "Alt" click with `Alt:: return`

But it doesn't work in Autohotkey v2.0.2.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try with casing as shown in the docs? So `Alt::Return`

Comment: @Destroy666, yes. Unfortunatelly, it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This disables the ability for the Alt key to activate the active window's menu bar,
while still allowing its use as a modifier:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

~Alt::Send "{Blind}{vkE8}"
```

For details see [A_MenuMaskKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/A_MenuMaskKey.htm).